# Multilevel join in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I was wondering if there is an easy way to get the parent (A) of a model (C) in Django, given that A has a many to many relationship with B, which has a many to many relationship with C?

edit:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   levels = models.ManyToManyField('Level', through="ProjectLevel",
       related_name='levels_project')

class Level(models.Model):
    areas = models.ManyToManyField('Area', through="LevelArea",
        related_name='areas_level')

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: It will be easier to provide you with an answer if you construct a simple django models code (e.g. with Book Library examples).

Comment: Sorry, I added some sample code. Project = A, Level = B and Area = C

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but I think the following code may work. Finger crossed :)

1. For a given project, you get a queryset of all the related levels
2. you iterate through this queryset to build an Area queryset by appending all areas for each level
   This way you should get all the "leaf" areas for a given project.

```
p = Project.objects.get(pk=1) # Get a specific project, change the query accordingly

levels = p.levels.all()
areas = None

for level in levels:
    areas = areas | level.areas.all()
```